# Include view page based on its route Zend2 Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How to include a page based on its route. Example of route: `page_to_be_included`

Page should be included like this in view:

```
<?php 
    if (...){
        include 'page_to_be_included';
    }
    else {
        show something else
    }
?>
```

How can i include one view in another view?

Comment: what's 'page_to_be_included'? Is it the controller name, action name or parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you means to include a view script (of an other controller)?

```
    $viewmodel = new ViewModel();
    $page = $this->forward()->dispatch('thecontroller', array(
        'action'    => 'youractionname',
    ));
    $viewmodel->addChild($page, 'page');
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases each route should lead to its own action, then each action can set its on view (or just use default).

If more then one route lead to the same action, you can check the route in the controller and set the view according:

```
if ( $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName() == 'the_route_name' ) {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('what/ever/page');
    return $viewModel->setVariables(array('var2pass'=>'hi'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to put partial into you view. If you want to do this just use `partia()` view helper in your view with specified string path to your partial.

Lets say you have folder structure of your Test module like this: module\Test\view\partial\name-of-partial.phtml

```
$this->partial('partials/name-of-partial');
```